# How do I evenly distribute a group of spans across a div?

Tags: css

I have an `aside` on the side of my webpage that contains `span` blocks that contain tags for blog posts. Right now, they're set up with `display: inline-table` that put multiple on each line and then go to the next line as overflow.

If possible (and JavaScript is okay, but CSS is preferred), how can I get these spans to take up the entire width inside of the `div` so I don't have the "rough edge" to the right? I'd like to either increase the margins between the `span` blocks or I'd be okay with increasing the width of the `span` as well.

Here's the code I currently have:

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #333332;
}
aside {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
h2 {
  margin: 24px;
  padding-top: 24px;
}
.tag-wrapper {
  padding: 0px 24px;
}
span {
  display: inline-table;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #F77C2F;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    <h2>Tags</h2>
    <div class="tag-wrapper">
      <span>finance</span>
      <span>if</span>
      <span>pv</span>
      <span>pivot tables</span>
      <span>vba</span>
      <span>test</span>
      <span>test</span>
      <span>test</span>
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little flexbox magic will get the job done:

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #333332;
}
aside {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
h2 {
  margin: 24px;
  padding-top: 24px;
}
.tag-wrapper {
  padding: 0px 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
}
span {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #F77C2F;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    <h2>Tags</h2>
    <div class="tag-wrapper">
      <span>finance</span>
      <span>if</span>
      <span>pv</span>
      <span>pivot tables</span>
      <span>vba</span>
      <span>test</span>
      <span>test</span>
      <span>test</span>
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

The properties used are:

1. `display: flex`: this sets the display type of the container to flex (aka flexbox)
2. `flex-flow: row wrap`: makes items order in a row, and wrap as required.
3. `align-content: stretch`: makes items stretch to fill the flex direction (row).
4. `flex 1 0 auto`: makes the items "growable" (1), but not "shrinkable" (0), and use self base width (auto) before distributing leftover space.

Comment: Works great, thanks! Could you briefly explain or point towards a resource that explains what `flex: 1 0 auto` means?

Comment: Also, what does `flex` look like on browsers that don't support CSS3 such as older versions of IE?

Comment: flexbox is [not supported for old IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), but it is supported by 95% (and growing) of all browsers. It's recommended to use property prefixes (`-webkit` etc...) for increased support.

Comment: Is there a way to tell what my webpage will look like for those few browsers that don't support flex?

Comment: As far as I recall, in IE you can use the developer tools to change compatibility mode to emulate older versions.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are talking about? If so, just change the display of the span to block instead of inline-block.

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #333332;
}
aside {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
h2 {
  margin: 24px;
  padding-top: 24px;
}
.tag-wrapper {
  padding: 0px 24px;
}
span {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #F77C2F;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    <h2>Tags</h2>
    <div class="tag-wrapper">
      <span>finance</span>
      <span>if</span>
      <span>pv</span>
      <span>pivot tables</span>
      <span>vba</span>
      <span>test</span>
      <span>test</span>
      <span>test</span>
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>
```